# Data.Table R: error merging greater than four DTs with Reduce and merge

Tags: r, merge, data.table

I have a list of 7 dts with the same dimension ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/39561045/revisions) 74  2) and colnames ("variable" and "V1") for example ;

```
> head(dt1)
    variable          V1
1:      A         4.213668
2:      B      1474.040190
3:      C         4.445173
4:      D        76.960665
5:      E        81.796707
6:      F       215.312311
```

Based on the script by Michael Ohlrogge   `MergedDT = Reduce(function(...) merge(..., all = TRUE), List_of_DTs)`  [revisions of Merging multiple data.tables](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/39561045/revisions), I came up with a following;

```
list<-list(dt1, dt2, ....dt7)

merged<-Reduce(function(...) merge(..., by="variable", all=T, allow.cartesian=T),list)
```

This works with a list of 4 its but beyond 4, I get this error,

```
error in merge.data.table(..., by = "variable", no.dups = F, all = T,  : 
  x has some duplicated column name(s): V1.k1,V1.k2. Please remove or rename the duplicate(s) and try again.
In addition: Warning message:
In merge.data.table(..., by = "variable", no.dups = F, all = T,  :
  column names 'V1.k1', 'V1.k2' are duplicated in the result
```

I'd appreciate any pointes to get around this issue.

Comment: Can you rename the column 'V1' in all the list elements i.e. `Map(setnames, list, 'V1', paste0('V', seq_along(list)))` and then run the `Reduce`

Comment: please make your example reproducible

Comment: @akrun, changing "V1" fixed the problem.  Could you kindly  show me a script to change "V1"  in multiple (hundreds) data.tables  rather than in the list ? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we need to change this in multiple datasets, load them into a `list` with `mget`.  Here, we assume the dataset object names starts with 'dt' followed by some digits

```
library(data.table)
lst1 <- mget(ls(pattern = '^dt\\d+$'))
lst1 <- Map(setnames, lst1, 'V1', paste0('V', seq_along(list)))
```